# Overflow scroll with padding Webkit v. Firefox

Tags: overflow, css

I'm trying to figure out why padding is included in this scrolling content for Chrome (Mac Version 27.0.1453.110) but not in Firefox (Mac 21.0). I'm using the `box-sizing: border-box;` When I hit the bottom the scrolling content the padding is there in Chrome, but in Firefox the last element is the bottom, there isn't any padding below. Should I be using margin instead? Is this a bug for 1 of the browsers?

I have an [example on codepen](http://cdpn.io/iwpjI)

CSS:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background-color: #222;
}

p {
 padding-bottom: 20px; 
}

.boxy {
  background-color: #111;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  height: 442px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 722px;
}

.inside-boxy {
  background-color: #ff6000;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 12px 50px 50px 28px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.in-links {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 132px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  width: 600px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Paul Irish Box Model FTW</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="boxy">

      <div class="inside-boxy">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
        <div class="in-links">links!</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like this is a Firefox bug? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518

Comment: Looking over the bug report it seems like Webkit is the browser that is out of step.    
  
> We're now compatible with IE10 which has the same layout.  
> Opera and webkit has the same layout as Fx11 and older.  
  
Note that Opera (w/ Presto) now matches us on this, so it looks like Webkit is the only engine that's applying the bottom-padding now.

Answer (score 0):

.inside-boxy has a fixed height. I would not issue the padding through that container. Instead, I would issue the padding and margin properties of the components inherent to .inside=boxy. I re-wrote your CSS below. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
       p {
 padding:20px; 
}

.boxy {
  background-color: #111;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  height: 442px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 722px;
}

.inside-boxy {
  background-color: #ff6000;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width:100%;
}

.in-links {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 132px;
  margin:20px 0 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
```